# How to convert 3 separate columns into a single date column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, to-date

I have the following data frame df, it looks like this:

```
Year Month Day Output
 61.0  1.0  1.0 10000
 61.0  1.0  2.0 15000
 61.0  1.0  3.0 17000
```

I want to put the cells of each first 3 columns into the format 19YY-MM-DD in a new column labeled 'Date' and then I want to add that column to the end of the data frame.

I tried the following:

```
datecolumn=df.loc[:,"Year":"Day"]
insertdate=pd.to_datetime(datecolumn[['Year','Month','Day']])
df['Mean']=insertdate
```

but it gives me a very long error message and at the end it says

```
ValueError:cannot assemble the datetimes:time data '61010' does not match format %Y%M%D
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What, is that 61 mean 1961? Year needs to be a 4 digit number.

Comment: @cs95: It is mentioned in `19YY-MM-DD`

Comment: I just started learning. I'm sorry I don't know it

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
df.Year = "19"+df.Year.astype(str)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it when I get home